# HTML code is being converted into corresponding HTML page into CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

I am using the [CKEditor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CKEditor) on my website to take input from users. When HTML code is copied from page and pasted into CKEditor, it is converted into the corresponding page. I mean When I insert this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Upload Image</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form action="Upload02" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                Image<input type="file" name="image" id="image" accept="image/jpg">
                <input type="submit" value="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It is converted into this:

[image: ckeditor_input_image]

I reported this issue to the CKEditor official website, but I got no help from them. I am using the CKEditor 4.5.8 full version. It is working properly in their demo, but not in the actual implementation. It is giving a problem only in copy-paste. In normal typing it's working properly. What can I do?

Comment: It looks like you want to take 'text only' input from your users. What is then the reason to use ckeditor (a rich text html based editor)? Probably you can do what you want to do with just a plain 'textarea' form field.

Comment: No. I want both text and code as input from user and I want markdown editing to be performed on it. That's why I used Ckeditor. I want the code to be saved as it is in my db.